# Непонятный вывод после использования artisan команд в (bash и windows terminal)?

Tags: laravel, bash, консоль

После установки Laravel 6 и использования artisan  команд получаю непонятный вывод в консоли.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выше миграция создается без ошибки.

Comment: Это раскрашиваение консоли в цвета. Нужно либо выключить его как-то, либо настроить терминал.

Comment: @TotalPusher, либо объяснить авторам того г...поделия как проверять терминал на совместимость с соответствующими критериями.

Comment: @0andriy, я не могу объяснить, увидел коды, написал причину, как пофиксить не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от этого, можно запускать artisan с флагом `--no-ansi`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php (это не вам, это скорее авторам поделия, впрочем, PHP — диагноз)